# Database Engine Independent Data Modelling

Tags: database

I'm looking for a tool where I maintain a simple data model, and then using possibly plugins, generate actual databases for MSSQL and mySQL, and as a bonus, others.  This should not be a whole ORM tool, just abstract to concrete data model.  Where should I look?  Who knows of one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some tools I've evaluated before

[CA ERWin Data Modeller](http://www.ca.com/us/products/product.aspx?ID=260)

[Visible Analyst DB Engineer](http://www.visible.com/Products/Analyst/vadbengineer.htm)

[TOAD Data Modeller](http://www.quest.com/toad-data-modeler/)

[ER Studio](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/erstudio/)

HTH

Comment: What was the result of your evaluation?